# Unix sed command

Tags: unix, sed

Надо в конфигурационном файле поменять путь. Как сделать это используя `sed`? 
`PATH=/home/user/folder/` на `PATH=/home/user/newfolder"`.

Пробовал так:

```
sed -i 's/PATH='/'home'/'user'/'folder'/PATH='/'home'/'user'/'newfolder/' file.txt
```

Ошибка:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'

Кто знает как можно правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
from="PATH=/home/user/folder/"
to="PATH=/home/user/newfolder"
sed -i "s,$from,$to," file.txt
```

См. [пример работы скрипта](https://ideone.com/AoQBrx).

Смысл в том, чтобы вместо символа косой черты в качестве разделителя использовать другой, такой, который не встречается ни в шаблоне поиска, ни в шаблоне замены.

Comment: works. спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> > sed -i 's/PATH='/'home'/'user'/'folder'/PATH='/'home'/'user'/'newfolder/' file.txt

Проблема в том, что / в адресе воспринимается sed не как символ, а как разделитель.
Используйте экран для решения подобных проблем

`sed -i 's/PATH=\/home\/user\/folder/PATH=\/home\/user\/newfolder/g' file.txt`

Так же можно изменить разделитель на |,.@ и т.д.

`sed 's|PATH=/home/user/folder/|PATH=/home/user/newfolder/|g'`